# always get "package not installed" in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi I always get the error running the application in Android on the emulator from Intel  but as I clean and refresh the App and run again it runs fine.

Why do get this when I try to run my App on emulator for the 2nd time  until I clean and run it again. Looking forward to some suggestion.

```
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691): Process: com.vertex.tymbox, PID: 2691
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.vertex.tymbox; is package not installed?
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:563)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4491)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.vertex.tymbox; is package not installed?
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:409)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:555)
04-05 20:47:20.943: E/AndroidRuntime(2691):     ... 10 more
```